# Mapping over Array of JSON

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How can I re-factor the below code to not change `i` or `initObj`?

```js
// input: [{name: "Kevin"}, {name: "Bob"}]
// output: {"Kevin" : 0, "Bob" : 1}
var map = function(arr, property) { 
    var i = 0;
    var initObj = {};
    
    var m = arr.map(makeKv);

    function makeKv(item) {
        initObj[item[property]] = i++;
        return initObj;
    };

    return m[0];
}

var x = map([{name: "Kevin"}, {name: "Bob"}], 'name');
alert(JSON.stringify(x, null, 4));
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is your goal?

Comment: I'm asking how to re-factor my above method to perform the desired functionality **without** changing the `i` variable and `initObj` object.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: In order to populate your object, you're going to need to change *some* variable.

Comment: You don't want to *map*, you want to *reduce*.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing low level stuff like this on your own, I suggest using underscorejs. http://underscorejs.org

Comment: I love underscore.js.  If you are using that, you can do: `_.chain(arr).map(function(x, i){ return [x[property], i]; }).object().value()` :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `{"Kevin" : 0, "Bob" : 1}` as your output, then `.map()` is the wrong tool here.  You want to use `.forEach` to loop over the array, then fill in `initObj`.

```
var map = function(arr, property) { 
    var initObj = {};
    arr.forEach(makeKv);

    function makeKv(item, index) {
        initObj[item[property]] = index;
    };

    return initObj;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FgdSj/9/

Comment: that's no doubt cleaner than what I have, but how can I not use any mutations?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: What do you mean "not use any mutations"?  What *exactly* is your goal here?  Do you have an actual problem you're trying to solve, or are you just trying to optimize?  I can't see how you can get any more optimized than this.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you would do this in Haskell:

```hs
import Data.Map.Strict hiding (foldl)

data Person = Person { name :: String }

input :: [Person]
input  = [Person "Kevin", Person "Bob"]

output :: Map String Int
output =  foldl inductive empty $ zip input [0..]
    where inductive result (person, index) = insert (name person) index result
```

Similarly, you can do it in JavaScript:

```js
var input  = [{ name: "Kevin" }, { name: "Bob" }];

var output = input.reduce(inductive, {});

alert(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4));

function inductive(result, person, index) {
    result[person.name] = index;
    return result;
}
```

Note that you don't need to `zip input [0..]` in JavaScript because the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method supplies the `index` of the element as the third parameter to the `inductive` function.

Also, we are still mutating the `result` object. You could create a new `result` object every time, copying the values of the old `result` to the new `result` and adding the new property. However, that would be very inefficient.